# How to retrieve record from SQl using Date as parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

in my table am storing one column(smalldatetime).

i need to retreive records by giving just date- and search the column specified above.

```
Ex:
```

10/6/2010 4:01:00 PM  - this is the actual value in Column.

And i just want to search records from table by givin today's date.  ..???

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDisplayAllOpenPrepaidSales]
@preStatus int,
@preCompanyId int,
@preCounterId int,
@preBillerId int,
 @today  smalldatetime 
AS 
BEGIN
print @today
select * from PrepaidSaleHeader 
where preOpenStatus = @preStatus And preCompanyId = @preCompanyId And 
preCounterId = @preCounterId And preEntryUserId = @preBillerId And preDate > @today
order by preDate
END
```

And pass parameter like;

```
spDisplayAllOpenPrepaidSales 0,2,4,2,'10/06/2010  00:00:00 AM'
```

Now this retreives record but gives me back - date in 24-hour Format.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL DateDiff function is your friend - see [SQL DataDiff Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDisplayAllOpenPrepaidSales]
@preStatus int,
@preCompanyId int,
@preCounterId int,
@preBillerId int,
@today  smalldatetime 
AS 
BEGIN
print @today
select * from PrepaidSaleHeader 
where preOpenStatus = @preStatus And preCompanyId = @preCompanyId And 
preCounterId = @preCounterId And preEntryUserId = @preBillerId 
And DateDiff(d,preDate,@today) = 0 --to find all dates matching the parameter, regardless of the time
order by preDate
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an ISO 8601 conformant format for the date, e.g.

```
spDisplayAllOpenPrepaidSales 0,2,4,2,'2010-10-06 00:00:00'
```

Times should be in 24hr form, not AM/PM form, so my local time now would be '13:02:00'.  If you want all records for today, because the date value includes time, anything past the absolute beginning of today (00:00:00) is actually bigger that today.  I always use the algorithm where myDate >= today and myDate < tomorrow, which translates to:

```
where preDate >= '2010-10-06' and preDate < '2010-10-07'
```

To achieve generality with this, use the DATEADD() function:

```
where preDate >= @today and preDate < DATEADD(day, 1, @today)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean you want to retrieve all records which match todays' date regardles of the time part?  If so you can do something quite simply, but clumsy as this.

Get the Day of year for teh column, and the year for the column, and compare against eh day of year for the current date and the year for the current date (Or whatever date you are comparing against).

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DATEPART(dy,MyColumn) = DATEPART(dy,GETDATE()) AND DATEPART(yy,MyColumn) = DATEPART(yy,GETDATE())
```

So your procedure would look like:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDisplayAllOpenPrepaidSales]
@preStatus int,
@preCompanyId int,
@preCounterId int,
@preBillerId int,
 @today  smalldatetime 
AS 
BEGIN
print @today
select * from PrepaidSaleHeader 
where preOpenStatus = @preStatus And preCompanyId = @preCompanyId And 
preCounterId = @preCounterId And preEntryUserId = @preBillerId And DATEPART(dy,preDate) = DATEPART(dy,@today)) AND DATEPART(yy,preDate) = DATEPART(yy,@today)
order by preDate
END
```

Comment: Or use DateDiff...(and what about the months... ?)

Comment: Months are irrelevant when using day of year - it goes from 1 to 365...  How does DATEDIFF handle if he passed in GETDATE and it was just before midnight?  Would he get todays records or records from teh last 24 hours?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, missed the "dy" :-)  DateDiff "counts specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate", so the time is effectivly ignored - passing in a time just before midnight you still just get matches for today.

Comment: Then your method is neater than mine, one fewer comparison made, and easier to type...  Not sure which would give better performance, but I'd imagine your method with DATEDIFF...  Voted your answer up...